# Convert date time with AM and PM to milisecound?

Tags: android, datetime

I am trying to convert the date and time to milliseconds but it is always giving me wrong answer please tell me how to convert this type of format date and time  "5/4/2014 4:39:52 PM" in millisecond

"5/4/2014 4:39:52 PM"

I am trying to wake alarm at particular date time and according to the am and pm

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [SimpleDateformat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
String dateString = "5/4/2014 4:39:52 PM";
SimpleDateFormat format = 
                new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
Date date = format.parse(dateString);
long millisecond = date.getTime();
```

This class is used to parse strings into dates in java.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
String dateString = "05/04/2014 4:39:52 PM";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
Date mDate = new Date();
try {
    mDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("TimeMilis : " +mDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date and .Calendar classes.

## Joda-Time

Here is some example code using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3.

```
String input = "5/4/2014 4:39:52 PM";

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ); // Or, DateTimeZone.UTC
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" );

DateTime dateTime = formatter.withZone( timeZone ).parseDateTime( input );
long millis = dateTime.getMillis();

DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "millis: " + millis );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
```

When run…

```
input: 5/4/2014 4:39:52 PM
dateTime: 2014-04-05T16:39:52.000+02:00
millis: 1396708792000
dateTimeUtc: 2014-04-05T14:39:52.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting AM and PM you can try below code,

```
private void updateTime(int hours, int mins) {

        String timeSet = "";
        if (hours > 12) {
            hours -= 12;
            timeSet = "PM";
        } else if (hours == 0) {
            hours += 12;
            timeSet = "AM";
        } else if (hours == 12)
            timeSet = "PM";
        else
            timeSet = "AM";

        String minutes = "";
        if (mins < 10)
            minutes = "0" + mins;
        else
            minutes = String.valueOf(mins);

        aTime = new StringBuilder().append(hours).append(':').append(minutes)
                .append(" ").append(timeSet).toString();
    }
```

just modify a bit code and it's variable name as per your requirement.

Comment: i have done this now i want to get milisec so that i can set alarm

Comment: for that you can simply use dateformate object like, `SimpleDateFormat = format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");`